# Carrierwave not utilizing default_url when version not present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

Essentially, the photo_url(:thumb) displays the intended thumb url even though the file doesn't physically exist.

```
# encoding: utf-8

class WinePhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

    include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

    storage :file

    # So the :thumb will be stored in "public/assets/wines/thumb/2008-meritage-750mL.jpg" for example.
    def store_dir
        "assets/wines/#{version_name}"
    end

    def cache_dir
        Rails.root.join 'tmp/uploads'
    end

    CarrierWave::SanitizedFile.sanitize_regexp = /[^[:word:]\.\-\+]/

    # If no version name is present (original), just provide the thumb path
    # This method is never called!!! Why not?
    def default_url
        ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("pages/wines/#{version_name || :thumb}/default.png")
    end

    # To save disk space, make sure the original image is no larger than the croppable + a few pixels
    process :resize_to_fit => [2000, 2000]

    version :croppable, :if => :not_cropping? do
        process :common
        process :resize_and_pad => [1200, 1200, :white]
        process :convert => "jpg"
        # Override the default naming convention...I store in folders,
        # so I don't want the version prepended to the file name.
        def full_filename(for_file = model.photo.file)
            the_filename
        end
    end

    version :show, :if => :not_cropping? do
        process :resize_to_show
        process :convert => "jpg"
        def full_filename(for_file = model.photo.file)
            the_filename
        end
    end

    version :thumb, :from_version => :croppable, :if => :viewing_or_cropping? do
        process :custom_thumbnail => [200, 200]
        def full_filename(for_file = model.photo.file)
            the_filename
        end
    end




    def common(q=100, s='1.2x1+0.75+0.05')
        manipulate! do |img|
            img.combine_options do |i|
            i.quality q
            i.antialias
            i.background :white
            i.flatten
            i.density 72
            i.profile "#{Rails.root}/lib/color_profiles/sRGB_v4_ICC_preference_displayclass.icc"
            i.strip
            end
            img = yield(img) if block_given?
            img.combine_options do |i|
            i.unsharp s
            end
            img
        end
    end

    def resize_to_show
        common do |img|
            img.combine_options do |i|
            i.trim
            i.thumbnail 110
            i.background :white
            i.gravity :center
            i.extent 170
            end
            img
        end
    end

    def custom_thumbnail(width, height)
        manipulate! do |img|
            img.combine_options do |i|
            i.distort :srt, "#{model.crop_x},#{model.crop_y} 1 -30 600,600"
            i.repage.+
            i.gravity :center
            i.crop "#{model.crop_w}x#{model.crop_h}+0+0"
            i.repage.+
            i.thumbnail "#{width}x#{height}"
            i.unsharp '1.2x1+0.75+0.05'
            end
            img
        end
    end




    def not_cropping? picture
        !model.cropping?
    end
    # For some stupid reason, if I only check for 'model.cropping?' and
    # it returns false, the photo_url(:thumb) will always show the default_url
    # and never show the actual url! This is terrible logic. The version declarations
    # above should only affect the generation of thumbnails, not whether the call
    # to photo_url(:thumb) works.
    def viewing_or_cropping? picture
        model.cropping? or model.changes.merge(model.previous_changes).empty?
    end

    # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
    # For images you might use something like this:
    def extension_white_list
        %w(jpg jpeg gif png tif tiff)
    end

    # Only modify the version names, not the original uploaded file name
    def filename
        "#{ model.get_permalink(:normalized => true) }#{ File.extname original_filename }" if original_filename
    end

    # The filename should be the wine's permalink name (ex., 2008-merlot-reserve-750mL.jpg)
    def the_filename
        "#{ model.get_permalink(:normalized => true) }.jpg"
    end

    # Remove this when https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1164 is solved.
    def recreate_versions!(*versions)
    if versions.any?
        from_versions = versions.group_by { |v| self.class.versions[v][:options][:from_version] }
        from_versions.each do |from, versions|
        next if from.nil?
        file = CarrierWave::SanitizedFile.new(self.versions[from.to_sym].file)
        store_versions!(file, versions)
        end
    else
        super(*versions)
    end
    end

end
```

So a call to @wine.photo_url(:thumb) produces

> http://dev.mydomain.com/assets/wines/thumb/2006-cabernet-sauvignon-750mL.jpg

when it should be producing

> http://dev.mydomain.com/assets/pages/wines/thumb/default.png

because the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that Carrierwave generates the file names based on the existence of the model's attribute in the database and not whether or not the specific version of the file exists. Not what I was expecting from default_url but it still makes sense in its limited way.